# Problem accessing the vuex mutations from inside of the store/index.js

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Humbly, I admit that I'm [gleaning from SAVuegram](https://github.com/savvyapps/SAVuegram/blob/master/src/store.js) in setting up authentication for my app. I am running Firebase's `onAuthStateChanged` to make certain the user stays logged in during page refreshes however I am completely unable to access the state inside of the function, receiving the following error.

[image: Error gaining access to store]
*(the $store is just from me taking a screenshot while testing "$store" as well as "store" - both break.)*

With strict debugging turned on I'm also getting messages warning me about mutating outside of mutation handlers, but isn't that what I'm doing? 
[image]

**Here's my store/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import fb from '../components/firebase/firebaseInit'
import createLogger from 'vuex/dist/logger'

// import dataRefs from './dataRefs'
// import pageTitle from './modules/pageTitle'
import auth from './modules/auth'
import apps from './modules/applicants'

Vue.use(Vuex)

fb.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      // here I can access the user object but never the following "store"
      console.log("FB AUTH", user);
      store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)
      store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
    }
});

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({

    state: {
        pageTitle: '',
        currentUser: null,
        userProfile: null
      },

    mutations: {

      changePageTitle(state, newTitle) {
        state.pageTitle = newTitle
      },

      changeSnackBarMessage(state, newMessage) {
        state.snackBarMessage = newMessage
      },

      // POPUPS
      changeAdvisorAddAppPopupStatus(state) {
        state.showAdvisorAddPopup = !state.showAdvisorAddPopup
      },

      setToken(state, token) {
        state.token = token;
      },

      setUser(state, userObj) {
        state.user.email = userObj.email;
        state.user.fbUUID = userObj.uuid;
      }
    },

  actions: {
      updatePageTitle(vuexContext, newTitle) {
        vuexContext.commit('changePageTitle', newTitle);
      },
      updateSnackBarMessage(vuexContext, newMessage) {
        vuexContext.commit('changeSnackBarMessage', newMessage);
      },
      toggleAdvisorAddPopup(vuexContext) {
        vuexContext.changeAdvisorAddAppPopupStatus
      },
  },

    modules: {
    auth,
    apps
    },
    strict: debug,
    plugins: debug ? [createLogger()] : []
  })
};
export default createStore;
```

FYI, I have also tried to instantiate my store by using `export const store = new Vuex.Store({` instead of the `const create ...` method but then Vuex show me that none of my state, actions, getters, or mutations are even found.

[image]

**Thanks for the help.**

Answer (score 0):

Why do you create the store in a function?

```
const createStore = () => {
```

I am just doing it like that:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {},

    mutations: {},

    actions: {},

    modules: {
       auth,
       apps
    },
    strict: debug,
    plugins: debug ? [createLogger()] : []
  })
};

export default store;
```

And i am able to access store now.

Comment: When I do that, I receive the error: `[nuxt] store/index.js should export a method which returns a Vuex instance.` I'm hoping this is not because of nuxt.js

Comment: I'm also setting up my store as per the nuxt vuex instructions (https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/). I was using the "classic" model.